# How to compare two totals from different datasets

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

We have three different file one is like that

File A

```
000001000
000002000
000003000 
000004000
```

File B (After Summing of all Records in file A)

```
000010000
```

File C

```
     Total : - 10000
```

I have to compare the value in the File C and File B and if the value matches successfully I have to set the desired Return Code RC.

The starting position of the word "Total" is five.

Comment: What's the 1 2 3 4... stuff?

Comment: Also, what are LRECL and RECFM of the input datasets?

Comment: Which sort product are you using?  Syncsort, DFSORT, etc.

Comment: 1234.... are the column

Comment: LRECL is 80 and the RECFM is FB

Comment: @cschneid i am using the DFSORT

Comment: No, you don't change your question like that when there are already answers. Put your explanation into your answer. Hope that your clients never see this question and your answer. Irony with your profile message.

Comment: Ironically, with what we now know from your attempted edit, you could do everything in that first SORT step, and not even need a new one. Oh. No you can't, because you've chosen to do it with JOINKEYS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also find the solution of the problem using the JOINKEY.

The code is given below.

```
//STEP1  EXEC PGM=SORT,PARM=’NULLOUT=RC4′                     
//SORTJNF1 DD DSN=FILEB                                   
//SORTJNF2 DD DSN=FILEC                                   
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                           
//SYSIN    DD *                                   
 JOINKEYS FILE=F1,FIELDS=(1,9,A) 
 JOINKEYS FILE=F2,FIELDS=(5,9,a) 
 REFORMAT FIELDS=(F1:1,80)                 
 OPTION COPY     
/*
```

When the Match is success full it will return the RC=0
And

When Match is not success full it will return the RC=4 as it is supplied using the PARM.

Basically it search for the record in the output file (sortout) if  Match successful the jcl sort utility will copy the record from fileB into the Output file(in spool) and if the unsuccessful match then the output file is empty and the with the help of PARM=’NULLOUT=RC4′ it return the RC=4.

Comment: So File A was a Red Herring? You now have to ensure a "chain of custody" from File A to File B. You can supply NULLOUT on the PARM or the OPTION statement. This won't work with the data you supplied, because your File C has trailing blanks in the number in the place of leading zeros. If you are going to start from File B, a simple concatenation will do it, rather than wasting your client's resources (they have to pay). Your last paragraph is non-sensical and misleading on so many levels. This is a bad choice for a solution, and it doesn't work with your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Why you wouldn't use JOINKEYS?**

A professional would know not to use `JOINKEYS` for this task or would recognise specific advice against using it.

For everyone else, here's why not.

JOINKEYS consists of three "Tasks", the Main Task and two Sub-Tasks (one for each input dataset). This means JOINKEYS can use up to three times the memory of a plain SORT/MERGE/COPY. This means a JOINKEYS step can be more difficult to "select" and can keep other JOBs from being selected. It also means a JOINKEYS step is going to be slower than an if an equivalent solution is possible not using JOINKEYS (this can depend on the exact solution, but is true for anything trivial).

More memory, more CPU, more elapsed time, more impact on other JOBs.

Only use JOINKEYS where necessary. Necessary does not mean "so I can type/copy-paste less code", it means when a good solution *requires* the use of JOINKEYS.

If a solution does not *require* JOINKEYS, then don't use JOINKEYS. Someone pays for the extra resources and impacts. A professional avoids such costs.

Of course, such advice is free, and you get what you pay for at times. However, I am the DFSORT Moderator at www.ibmmainframes.com, taking over that task from Frank Yaeger of IBM, the inventor of the modern DFSORT.

Plus in the sample code given by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5433120/sharad-singhal, the JOINKEYS won't even work with the data that they themselves showed in the question, as the field-types are different (one left-zero filled, the other leading-zero truncated, right-space-padded).

You can of course normalise the second key, using a `JNF2CNTL DD` and some code (the code needed is included here).

But. Even. Though. It. Can. Be. Made. To. Work. JOINKEYS. Is. A. Bad. Solution. For. This. Task.

I hope this is clear for any future searchers.

---

> I have to set the desired Return Code RC

This is impossible, except by coincidence. The only Condition Code/Return Code (CC/RC) available to you from DFSORT is zero, four and 16.

Perhaps that provides one of the CC/RC which you desired. If not, change your desire. Or do it the odd way around by using an IDCAMS step to "convert" the CC/RC you get from DFSORT to the CC/RC you so desperately want.

The only way you can get, with correct control cards, other than a zero RC is by having an empty output file (either SORTOUT or an OUTFIL dataset).

You want to SUM. SUM requires SORT or MERGE. You can also use OUTFIL reporting functions, REMOVECC and TOTAL to get sums, but by that time you don't have an opportunity to test that two totals are equal, or not.

Matching datasets is a good task for JOINKEYS.

You can also code the summation yourself.

Resource-wise and since you are probably a beginner, the best solution will be the MERGE.

You need two DD's in your JCL, SORTIN01 and SORTIN02, in place of SORTIN which you would usually have for a SORT step. You will also need at least one output DD, which can be SORTOUT, but best as another, and this should be set to DUMMY or DSN=NULLFILE.

You need to arrange that all the value records get a "key" which is equal, so that they can be SUMmed, and your Total record should get a different value.

```
//MATCHTOT EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYMNAMES DD * 
* IN- is the input records with values (and the summed value later)
* EXT- are temporary extensions made to the record for processing 
* TOT- is the total record 
* IND- is an indicator determining wheter value or total record 
IN-RECORD,*,80,CH 
EXT-IN-IND,*,1,CH 
EXT-TOT-TOTAL-VALUE,*,9,zd 
POSITION,IN-RECORD 
IN-VALUE,=,9,ZD 
IN-SUM-VALUE,=,=,= 
POSITION,IN-RECORD 
SKIP,5 
TOT-TOTAL-NAME,*,5,CH 
SKIP,5 
TOT-TOTAL-VALUE,*,9,CH 
* Constants 
TOTAL-TEXT,C'Total' 
IND-TOT-TOTAL,C'0' 
IND-IN-VALUE,C'5' 
CLOBBER-FIRST-PART,C'000000000' 
//SYMNOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//CHECK    DD DUMMY 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//FILEB DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 

  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(TOT-TOTAL-NAME,
                 EQ, 
                TOTAL-TEXT), 
                 OVERLAY=(EXT-IN-IND: 
                           IND-TOT-TOTAL, 
                          IN-VALUE: 
                           CLOBBER-FIRST-PART)), 
        IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE, 
                 OVERLAY=(EXT-IN-IND: 
                           IND-IN-VALUE)) 

  MERGE FIELDS=(EXT-IN-IND,A) 

  SUM FIELDS=(IN-VALUE) 

  OUTREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=GROUP, 
                  BEGIN=(EXT-IN-IND, 
                          EQ, 
                         IND-TOT-TOTAL), 
                  PUSH=(EXT-TOT-TOTAL-VALUE: 
                         TOT-TOTAL-VALUE)), 

         IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT, 
                  OVERLAY=(EXT-TOT-TOTAL-VALUE: 
                            EXT-TOT-TOTAL-VALUE,UFF,
                            TO=ZD, 
                            LENGTH=9)) 

  OUTFIL FNAMES=CHECK, 
         INCLUDE=(EXT-IN-IND, 
                   EQ, 
                  IND-IN-VALUE, 
                 AND, 
                  IN-SUM-VALUE, 
                   EQ, 
                  EXT-TOT-TOTAL-VALUE), 
         NULLOFL=RC4 

  OUTFIL FNAMES=FILEB, 
         INCLUDE=(EXT-IN-IND,CH,EQ,IND-IN-VALUE), 
         BUILD=(IN-RECORD) 

//SORTIN01 DD * 
000001000 
000002000 
000003000 
000004000 
//SORTIN02 DD * 
     Total : - 20000
```

This uses DFSORT symbols/SYMNAMES. These are defined on the SYMNAMES DD (best as a PDSE (or PDS) member, fixed-length 80-byte records.

The SYMNOUT DD statement lists the source symbols, and the normalised symbols which will by used by DFSORT to translate the control cards.

In INREC, the key for the merge is established and in the case of the Total record, the input positions (no longer required) that match the value on the value records are set to zero. Any data from an input file which is not needed for output can be happily destroyed (if it is not written, it is not written, so its content is irrelevant and can be amended if convenient to do so).

The MERGE then uses the key just established. This is just a trick to allow SUM to be used. All the value records (key five) will be SUMmed to an actual value, the total record will be left as it is (since its key is unique).

In OUTREC, the total from the Total record will be PUSHed to the next record (the SUMmed values) using WHEN=GROUP. The Unsigned Free Format data of the Total record will be converted to a Zoned Decimal value.

There are then two OUTFIL statements.

The first looks at the SUMmed record and compares the value to the value PUSHed from the Total record. If they are equal, a record is written to the OUTFIL (which is DUMMY in the JCL). The RC4 will not be set. If the values are different, no record will be written and the RC4 will be set.

The second OUTFIL is to create your FILEB, which is not itself needed as a file. If you don't need FILEB for anything else, you can remove this OUTFIL.

I have left the SORTOUT DD in the JCL so you can see what happens to the records. You can remove this once you are happy you know what is going on.

The only other RC you can get is 16. Avoid this as 16 is also produced for Control Card or run-time errors.